Negative value forced zero when assigned to uint16_t variable in C
I understand that unsigned and signed integers are just a different representation of the underlying bits according to two's complement. That is, the following is my observation -- b is a non-zero integer, good:
// gcc main.c -o main.out && ./main.out
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
void main() {
  int16_t a = -42;
  uint16_t b = a;
  printf("a = %d\n", a); // a = -42
  printf("b = %d\n", b); // b = 65494
}

Now, I have a colleague who claims to have evidence that in our embedded software project (I could not get the compiler toolchain details so far), b may be limited to b = 0 instead!
Processor seems to be an S32G.
Question: Is there any setting in the GCC compiler toolchain, or is there a CPU architecture, that makes unsigned to signed value assignment a limiting operation?
I have tried to compile with -ftrapv to force prevent the underflow, but that produces the same result as above...
UPDATE: I have found the error to be elsewhere: an intermediate assignment had cast float to uint16_t, which appears to be a wholly different problem with possibility of UB. The question is answered. I was more like:
// gcc main.c -o main.out && ./main.out
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
void main() {
  float a = -42;
  uint16_t b = a;
  printf("a = %.1f\n", a); // a = -42.0
  printf("b = %d\n", b); // b = ???
}


From the standard: "When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than _Bool, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined"

The problem is probably more like float f = 32768; uint16_t b = 0; int16_t a = f; b=a; where the result b==0 is not even surprising. Once Undefined Behavior happens, anything can happen afterwards. That definitely includes nothing happening.

ISO C requires this program to print 65494 ; conversion from an integer type to an unsigned integer type is required to modulo-reduce into the value-range of the destination type.  (In this case add 2¹⁶ to bring it into the 0..65535 range).  Conversion from an FP type doesn't have this guarantee; out-of-range is UB for FP→integer.
(Except if int is only 16-bit, then the default argument promotions for variadic functions won't promote uint16_t to int, so the arg type will be unsigned and won't match the %d conversion, in which case the behaviour is undefined.  Of course in practice it would just print -42 on a 2's complement system.  Use %u with (unsigned int)b or use PRIu16 in the format string to make it well-defined everywhere.  Thanks to Eric for pointing this out.)

In practice on 2's-complement systems, this just means truncating the bit-pattern if necessary, or sign-extending or zero-extending a narrow source.
So no, unless GCC has a nasty and easy-to-detect bug that would have affected a lot of code that casts negative numbers to unsigned and back, e.g. for bithacks.
Clamping negative numbers to zero would require an extra instruction on all ISAs, since int16 to uint16 requires zero.  (The GNU dialect of C guaranteed 2's complement signed integers long before C23.  GCC doesn't support any non-2's-complement targets.)

I have tried to compile with -ftrapv to force prevent the underflow

There is no signed-integer overflow here.  And BTW, even conversion to a signed integer type isn't UB as long as the source is also integer (not FP for example), although the result for out-of-range is implementation-defined in older C versions like C17.
C++23 changed to require 2's-complement representation, and simplified the rule so even conversion to signed integer modulo-reduces by a power of 2.  C23 also requires / guarantees 2's complement, but I haven't checked the wording on conversion to signed integer.  Hopefully it's the same; C and C++ try to stay in sync with each other when it makes sense.

Re: your edit mentioning float:

iphone: floats cast to unsigned ints get set to 0 if they are negative?

Is the behaviour of casting a negative double to unsigned int defined in the C standard? Different behaviour on ARM vs. x86

unsigned conversion in C works as expected on x86 but not ARM


(Godbolt) GCC for ARM uses vcvt.u32.f32 as the first step in converting float to uint16_t.  (I used volatile so the conversion would happen at run-time, not compile-time constant propagation.)
        vcvt.u32.f32    s16, s16
        vmov    r3, s16 @ int
        uxth    r1, r3

This instruction truncates the float value (rounding toward zero) and gives the nearest representable integer value to that.  This means it saturates to the value-range of uint32_t.  So negative numbers become zero.  (TODO: find an ARM manual that says that.  ARM's online HTML references that come up in google searches aren't very detailed, not mentioning any of that.)

as a sidenote: the opposite (uint16 to int16) is implementation-defined.

@Raildex: I was already adding a second section to the answer re: -ftrapv where I mentioned that before I saw your comment. :)

Quick thanks for the answer and the reference to ISO C. It all hints at something else going on in the code...

@fschwaiger: Yup, it's almost certainly not a compiler bug in the conversion.  Try gcc -fsanitize=undefined, and/or set a watchpoint on the variable being assigned to or from which sometimes gets zero.  Out-of-bounds writes could be zeroing something.  Maybe add if (x<0) { volatile int sink = x; } so you can set a breakpoint that triggers only on conversions with negative inputs, and see what's happening.

Re “ISO C requires this program to print 65494”: Not quite, if int were 16 bits, printf("b = %d\n", b) would not be defined, since the unsigned int argument would not match the %d conversion.

@EricPostpischil The ISA is mentioned in the question, S32 is a Cortex M4. So int is not 16 bits and any nit-picks about what would happen on other systems aren't relevant to this post.

The type of system used doesn't matter much here as this code is fully portable. (Though this is for a Cortex M so it's little endian with 32 bit 2's complement.)
Specifically, this is what C requires to happen:

int16_t a = -42; An implicit conversion during assignment from -42 which is 32 bit int to int16_t happens. -42 can fit just fine in a int16_t so the value is preserved.

uint16_t b = a;. An implicit conversion during assignment occurs1). This conversion is well-defined and portable, we end up with decimal value 65494.

One more than the maximum value of an uint16_t = 65536.
-42 + 65536 = 65494. This is in range of uint16_t.
Or if you will, take the raw binary representation of -42 in an int16_t which is 0xFFD6 and translate that to the decimal value representation of an uint16_t.


As for printing these numbers with %d, since they are small integer types in this case, there will be a "default argument promotion" to int. And since the result is representable as int in this case, the compiler will give you the values -42 and 65494 respectively.
Instead of %d this should have been PRIi16 and PRIu16 respectively, from inttypes.h.



1) C23 6.3.1.3 "Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting
one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type." This is the mathematical result of such arithmetic, without any C-related concerns about types of the operands. 

Printing these with %d is not undefined behavior except for uint16_t when int is 16 bits. The default argument promotion is standard, not just in practice. int16_t is promoted to int, and %d is correct for that. When int is not 16 bits, uint16_t is also promoted to int, and %d is correct for that.

@EricPostpischil Huh was this changed with C23? Previous versions had 7.21.6.1 §9 "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined." And that regardless of the default argument promotions. But C23 is different I noticed now.

It is not and never was regardless of the default argument promotions. That would be unworkable, as it would render printf("%c", c) undefined for a char c, since %c expects an int. The preparation of the function call proceeds as specified in C 2018 6.5.2.2 / C 2024 6.5.3.3, which specifies the default argument promotions. That is independent of the printf specification. The printf specification in C 2018 7.21.6.1 / C 2024 7.23.6.2 even mentions that the arguments will have been promoted.

@EricPostpischil Regardless, the C23 rewording rules out any inconsistencies. I updated the answer to match C23 7.21.6.1 §9.
